# Reset string while keeping capacity

Tags: c++, string

I've read a lot of questions here on SO about how to clear a string entirely (i.e. resetting the capacity, freeing memory). My question though is the exact opposite; is there any reliable way of resetting a string (the length) while being guaranteed that its capacity is kept intact?

Example: reusing a temporary string in a loop.

Likely this will happen by default if I do something like

```
str.clear()
str.reserve(256)
```

in each loop iteration, at least when using Visual Studio according to the answer to this post: [Specific behaviour of std::string on visual studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8386639/specific-behaviour-of-stdstring-on-visual-studio)

But relying on "likely" seems a bit risky.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/clear `clear()` doesn't free internal buffer and keeps `capacity` intact.

Comment: Hah, so it says. Guess I don't even have to call str.reserve(256) then, it will be kept anyway. I should check out the documentation better before posting here...